# Tesla Coil Slayer Circuit Not Working [Electroboom's design]

Tags: circuit-analysis, troubleshooting

I tried to make the following tesla coil slayer circuit but it doesn't even turn on. Below are some pictures of what I have constructed. I'm using 3 18650 batteries as the power supply.

I'm not sure how to power the circuit given the schematic, I tried connecting D2 and Q1 (1N4148 and IPI70R950CEXKSA1 mosfet) to earth, and the battery + and - to R2 and the top of the primary coil(L1) respectively, which did nothing. I also tried connecting R2 and L1 to the + end and D2 and Q1 to the negative end, U1 (MIC 4452YM) started gently smoking after this. Hopefully I didn't fry it :(. I also tried flipping polarity and everything in between, to no avail.

Also, I'm using 10 turns for the primary and 2200 turns on the secondary. I don't know how this ratio would impact performance though.

Any tips would be appreciated!

[image: Diagram https://www.electroboom.com/?p=521]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the part number for U1?

Comment: It is mosfet driver MIC 4452YM